# You have an error in your SQL syntax - using Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: mysql, database, syntax-error, pentaho

While trying to run this SQL syntax in Pentaho Data Integration:

```
USE hobbyhuset_dw;

INSERT INTO dim_kunde
SELECT
 NULL,
 knr,
 CONCAT(fornavn," ", etternavn),
 kjønn,
 k.postnr,
 poststed
FROM hobbyhuset.kunde k,hobbyhuset.poststed p
WHERE k.postnr = p.postnr;
```

I get this error on the preview:

```
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : Uventet feil
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 - An error occurred executing SQL: 
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 - USE hobbyhuset_dw;
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 - INSERT INTO dim_kunde
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 - SELECT
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 -  NULL,
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 -  knr,
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 -  CONCAT(fornavn," ", etternavn),
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 -  kjønn,
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 -  k.postnr,
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 -  poststed
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 - FROM hobbyhuset.kunde k,hobbyhuset.poststed p
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 - WHERE k.postnr = p.postnr;
2015/04/14 15:04:10 - Table input.0 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO dim_kunde
```

Other syntaxes towards the database works fine as long as I use the connection spesifically towards `hobbyhuset_dw`. The SQL syntax shown at the top also works perfectly well within MySQL Workbench. It seems to me that the "USE" syntax for changing between databases (in my case, I want to swap between hobbyhuset_dw and hobbyhuset (source)) doesn't. What is the correct syntax for USE in Pentaho ? Has it really depricated ? or is there a completely different solution to this?

You can see the pentaho version in the error output.
I'm currently using `MySQL Workbench 6.2.5.0 build 397(32bit)` towards a `MySQL server 5.6.`

Comment: try instead of USE hobbyhuset_dw; in from clause hobbyhuset_dw.kunde k, hobbyhuset_dw.poststed p

Answer (score 0):

`Table input` step should be used to obtain data from one database connection. Here it seems you try to select data from source database (source connection) and insert it directly into target database (target connection).

You should rather use those two steps (1st linked to 2nd):

1. **Table input** (obtains data from source database)

   - Connection: `hobbyhuset`
   - SQL:

     ```
     SELECT
       NULL,
       knr,
       CONCAT(fornavn," ", etternavn),
       kjønn,
       k.postnr,
       poststed
     FROM hobbyhuset.kunde k,hobbyhuset.poststed p
     WHERE k.postnr = p.postnr;
     ```
2. **Table output** (Inserts data to target database / DWH)

   - Connection: `hobbyhuset_dw`
   - Target table: `dim_kunde`
   - Database fields: Mapping of `record stream fields (srouce columns)` to `target table columns`